# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable when using ucimlrepo

Tags: python, dataset, typeerror, data-analysis

I want to use the [Adult dataset from the UCI ML Repo](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/2/adult).

For this I'm following the "import in python" option in the page, which gives this code:

```
pip install ucimlrepo

from ucimlrepo import fetch_ucirepo 
  
# fetch dataset 
adult = fetch_ucirepo(id=2) 
  
# data (as pandas dataframes) 
X = adult.data.features 
y = adult.data.targets 
  
# metadata 
print(adult.metadata) 
  
# variable information 
print(adult.variables)
```

But that raises the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/.../playground.ipynb Cell 3 line 4
      1 from ucimlrepo import fetch_ucirepo
      3 # fetch the adult dataset
----> 4 adult = fetch_ucirepo(id=2)
      6 # convert the dataset to a Pandas DataFrame
      7 df = pd.DataFrame(adult.data.features, columns=adult.variables.names, missing_values=["?"])

File ~/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ucimlrepo/fetch.py:148, in fetch_ucirepo(name, id)
    142 # alternative usage?: 
    143 # variables.age.role or variables.slope.description
    144 # print(variables) -> json-like dict with keys [name] -> details
    145 
    146 # make nested metadata fields accessible via dot notation
    147 metadata['additional_info'] = dotdict(metadata['additional_info'])
--> 148 metadata['intro_paper'] = dotdict(metadata['intro_paper'])
    150 # construct result object
    151 result = {
    152     'data': dotdict(data),
    153     'metadata': dotdict(metadata),
    154     'variables': variables
    155 }

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I know that i can download this database and then load it as a pandas df but this is more dirty because then i need to do some extra parsing and its not looking good (First load adult.data and second add the headers from the specific lines in adult.names (after splitting everything after the ":" in each line...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks.

I found that the simplest way to do it was to use [the url as given in the github issues page](https://github.com/uci-ml-repo/ucimlrepo/issues/2):

```
url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/static/public/2/data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems some datasets are deprecated but they didn't update their sample code.

```
from ucimlrepo import fetch_ucirepo, list_available_datasets
list_available_datasets()

fetch_ucirepo(id=17)
```

But still some datasets are available. If you have a chance, you can try the other ones.

Edit:

Actually, i checked their repo at https://github.com/uci-ml-repo/ucimlrepo/blob/main/src/ucimlrepo/fetch.py and you dont get error. Therefore if you fork the repo, and edit/delete below part, you can solve your issue.

```
metadata['additional_info'] = dotdict(metadata['additional_info'])
metadata['intro_paper'] = dotdict(metadata['intro_paper'])
```

Answer (score 1):

In looking at the [source code](https://github.com/uci-ml-repo/ucimlrepo/blob/main/src/ucimlrepo/fetch.py#L13C57-L13C57), it essentially makes the following API call `https://archive.ics.uci.edu/api/dataset?id=2` which returns

```
{'status': 200,
 'statusText': 'OK',
 'data': {'uci_id': 2,
  'name': 'Adult',
  'repository_url': 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/2/adult',
  'data_url': 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/static/public/2/data.csv',
  'abstract': 'Predict whether income exceeds $50K/yr based on census data. Also known as "Census Income" dataset. ',
  'area': 'Social Science',
  'tasks': ['Classification'],
  'characteristics': ['Multivariate'],
  'num_instances': 48842,
  'num_features': 14,
  'feature_types': ['Categorical', 'Integer'],
  'demographics': ['Age', 'Income', 'Education Level', 'Other', 'Race', 'Sex'],
  'target_col': ['income'],
  'index_col': None,
  'has_missing_values': 'yes',
  'missing_values_symbol': 'NaN',
  'year_of_dataset_creation': 1996,
  'last_updated': 'Mon Aug 07 2023',
  'dataset_doi': '10.24432/C5XW20',
  'creators': ['Barry Becker', 'Ronny Kohavi'],
  'intro_paper': None,

   ...
```

Notice that `intro_paper` is `None` which is why you are getting the `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone is looking for how to use the datasets. (yeah just me...)

```py
x = adult.data.features 
y = adult.data.targets
```

Using `X['Age']` we can get the age's numbers
Using numpy can convert the features into np.array

```py
x_train = np.array(X)
```